# How to improve the performance of getting PHAssetResource data?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have an about 7000 picture in my iPhone's photo library. Here is how I get all the pictures:

```
[allPhotos enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

            PHAsset *asset = (PHAsset *)obj;
            NSLog(@"idx = %lu", (unsigned long)idx);
}];
```

The above code takes about 3 seconds to go through 7000 pictures.

But my question is when I want to get the "originalFileName" it becomes very very slow, it takes about 0.5 seconds for each picture.

```
[allPhotos enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

        PHAsset *asset = (PHAsset *)obj;

        NSArray *resources = [PHAssetResource assetResourcesForAsset:asset];
        NSString *path = ((PHAssetResource *)resources[0]).originalFilename;
        path = [path lowercaseString];

        NSLog(@"idx = %lu", (unsigned long)idx);
}];
```

This line of code below has poor performance:

```
NSArray *resources = [PHAssetResource assetResourcesForAsset:asset];
```

Please help me.

Comment: Logically why would you need original filename for 7000 images at once? `Curious`

Comment: I need to use this to compare image from the external storage, see if the image already exist in the iOS photo library or not.

Comment: Can you access content of `External Storage`? You can choose to compare EXIF information of an image rather than comparing the image, check these categories that might help you [PHAsset-Meta](https://github.com/alexanderkent/PHAsset-Meta) and [PHAsset-Utility](https://github.com/zakkhoyt/PHAsset-Utility).

Comment: any update or solution for the slow fetching asset resources without using `asset valueForKey`?

Answer (score 2):

If you need originalFilename only, you can use

```
NSString *fileName = [asset valueForKey:@"filename"];
```